# Selenium Element cannot be scrolled into view - Multiple windows

Tags: java, selenium

I have several WebDriver instances running (through separate Java processes) selenium tests. My problem is that I get a lot the following error:

Element cannot be scrolled into view:
Command duration or timeout: 43 milliseconds

When I execute tests with one single window, everything runs correctly.

Is it possible that the element can't be scrolled in to screen because the window is smaller? I'm using small sized windows.
Does resizing the window while the test is running affects webdriver?
Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll the page using your script to bring element into the view. Example below:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found similar problem as error message is

> Element  could not be
>   scrolled into view Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown',
>   time: 'unknown'

I found this problem several days and it was failed in many functions. After investigation, then it should cause from not enough waiting time ! Then I have fixed it by increasing waiting time till the expect conditions is ready.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(pages, "something"));
```